# Flutter error in C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7

Tags: flutter, dart

Got the error after upgrading flutter

C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:280: error: cannot find symbol
settings.setAppCachePath(options.appCachePath);
^
symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)
location: variable settings of type WebSettings

Answer (score 1):

Do flutter clean
Then flutter pub get